# Anyway to start/stop/resume/pause a Storyboard in pure XAML in Silverlight, for any event?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, xaml, storyboard

Any way in Silverlight to write pure XAML code for controlling story boards, by responding to any given event for a given control? For eg, when the user move the mouse over a panel, I might need to start the storyboard, and pause it when he moves the mouse out.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you look a little bit into Nikhil Kothari's SilverlightFX framework (if you aren't already).  He's done a lot of work on declarative events through XAML.  May not do exactly what you're looking to do here but it sounds like you're looking to do more things like that.

His blog, which is very good, is here: http://nikhilk.net/Default.aspx

and the page for his framework is here:
http://projects.nikhilk.net/SilverlightFX